# Nodejs How to redirect facebook/twitter crawler bot to another server-generated page?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am building a small app and the crawlers that scrape the HTML when I share the page do not evaluate JavaScript(Makes sense). So what I'd like to do is use some kind of server-side user-agent detection to pick up whenever a social media crawler arrives, and then instead of showing it the plain AngularJS template file, redirect it to a server-generated page that will contain the desired meta tags, all filled with the correct information. I know there's prerender.io that can do this but is there a simple way we can do this using NodeJS/ExpressJS?

Comment: Do you have a `robots.txt` defined?

Comment: @zero298 not really, how that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can key off of the `user-agent` property of the request argument in your router.

Twitter states that the user agent its crawler uses will be something along the lines of `Twitterbot/X.X` (with `X.X` being a version string) in its [Getting Started documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started):

> Twitter uses the User-Agent of Twitterbot (with version, such as
>   Twitterbot/1.0), which can be used to create an exception in the
>   robots.txt file.

So a naive implementation would be:

```
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    if (/^Twitter/.test(req.headers["user-agent"])) {
        return res.redirect("/twitter-friendly");
    }
    res.send("You're not Twitter!");
});

app.get("/twitter-friendly", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello Twitter");
});
```

Testing with cURL:

```
curl -L -A "Twitterbot/1.0" http://localhost:3001/test
```

Gives output:

```
Hello Twitter
```

I would imagine that other crawlers that don't execute JavaScript follow a similar format and a similar strategy could be adopted.